# Making all the individuals different at once in Protégé

Tags: protege

In Protégé editor, how can we make all the individuals different at once? It seems time consuming adding each individual one by one.

To my memory, there was a method to make all the individuals different in Protégé 3.0, but how to do it in Protégé 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

In my Protege 5.5.0 this option is available under `Edit` - please see image below:

[image]